# Term for insulting words which sound grand?

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

I don't mean euphemisms or backhanded compliments (or the reverse). It's the words which *sound* grand, but actually have a bad meaning (e.g., *jumentous*: smelling strongly like a beast of burden). Is there any word to define this conceptually?

Comment: "The title says it all" - now.  Your edit makes this an entirely different question from the one you originally posted.  Better form would have been to post a new one, I think.

Comment: In my head it was obvious. I see now it can be read differently. Edited to clarify. Thanks.

Comment: what is that makes you example - '*jumentous*' sound 'grand'? (similarity with *momentous* and *gargantous*? an ending of *-ous*? the fact that it is not common?)

Comment: Not an answer, but one of my favorite examples - In one of the Kai Lung stories (don't have it handy to check which), Kai Lung addresses a pompous but relatively unlettered mandarin as "Your excrescence".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Sesquipedalianism](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sesquipedalianism)** is the habit of using long (*sesquipedalian*, or "foot-and-a-half") words; it doesn't specifically mean "using long words in order to disguise insults", but a few people I know who are habitual *sesquipedalianists*<sup>1</sup> do so for exactly that reason.

**[Obscurantism](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/obscurantism)** is "deliberate obscurity or evasion of clarity"; if you habitually use long words to hide your true meaning, you're an obscurantist.

I can't think of any word that combines those meanings with the specific intent to hide insults.

---

<sup>1</sup> This word doesn't seem to actually exist yet, so I'm coining it.  "Sesquipedalian" is the adjective form, but it refers to the words themselves, not the people who [mis]use them.

Answer (score 4):

Some phrases to describe the process: **[damning with faint praise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damn_with_faint_praise)**, a **[left-handed compliment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backhanded_compliment)**, **[asteism](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/asteism)**.

Some examples:

- Brave (often means *stupid*: "That's brave of you!")
- Interesting (can mean *boring*: "How very interesting." or *stupid*: "An interesting idea.  Why don't you present that at the next staff meeting?")
- Special (its sense of *developmentally disabled* was originally meant as a polite euphemism, as in the [Special Olympics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_Olympics) or *special needs*... but because of that association, one can sneer at **anything** by calling it "special", while appearing to praise it.  "Oh, did your kid make that mug for you?  Well, isn't that special?")
- Great personality (when you're being set up for a blind date, if your friend tells you that your date has "a great personality", it means s/he is ugly.  Or at least that's the cliché.)

Comment: The asker specifically says they don't want backhanded compliments, or those used ironically, but words that really mean something insulting.

Comment: +1 For asteism. I think this is a good answer.  It is "polite mockery."  I think it applies because the words are "polite" insofar as they sound nice, but "mockery" because they are not actually nice.  @MT_Head I think this answer could be improved by removing the sarcastic uses of nice words, and instead giving examples of nice-sounding insults.  Unless you think I am being too quixotic. :)

Comment: @Hugo - Here's the title and text of the original question (to which this was my answer): "What are some insulting words which sound like praise? - The title says it all. Is there any word to define this conceptually?"  The OP changed his question after my answer.

Comment: @Kit - I see what you did there...

Answer (score 1):

I'd say 'ostentatious' sounds quite grand, but is generally a bit of an insult.

Comment: But the OP is asking for a word that describes these kinds of insults.

Answer (score -2):

An insult that can sound like a compliment if you say it with a smile 'You are amazingly obsequious ". Sounds like a compliment but it really means you are an amazing brown noser

Comment: This does not answer the question. The asker wants to know a general term for the phenomenon, not additional examples.